# Delete data from three different tables that is related

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three SQL tables proyects, tasks and activities. The thing is that tasks are assigned to a proyect and activities to tasks. If I want to delete that proyect I have to delete all tasks for that proyect and all activities for those tasks. I want to write an SQL sentence that will, first show me that I am selecting the rows to delete correctly befere I actually delete them. Here is the sentece I wrote:

```
SELECT  activities.description, 
    activities.task, 
    tasks.user, 
    tasks.name, 
    tasks.proyect 
FROM tasks  JOIN proyects WHERE task.proyect=proyects.name 
        JOIN activities WHERE activities.task=tasks.name;
```

However this is throwing the check your syntax error near: 'JOIN activities WHERE activities.task=tasks.name'

I do not know what is wrong. I've checked the names of the tables and they are correct.

Comment: it will be `JOIN proyects ON` not `JOIN proyects WHERE`, it will be good to use [Foreign Key Constrain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) to do this type to thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax is wrong. Should be `ON` in the first one:

```
SELECT  activities.description, 
    activities.task, 
    tasks.user, 
    tasks.name, 
    tasks.proyect 
FROM tasks  JOIN proyects ON task.proyect=proyects.name 
        JOIN activities WHERE activities.task=tasks.name;
```

To delete all those results from the table, you can do this way:

```
DELETE FROM `tasks` WHERE `task` IN (
    SELECT  activities.task, 
    FROM tasks  JOIN proyects ON task.proyect=proyects.name 
            JOIN activities WHERE activities.task=tasks.name;)
```

Comment: Yes this is it however, the query did not work. But that is another question I suppose. Thank you.

Comment: Tried it. Did not work. The first error I got was Unknown column task. I assumed it was the task after the first WHERE and that it was supposed to be name (the task name). After I changed it I got this error: You can't specify target table 'tasks' for update in FROM clause
Whic I don't know what it means

Comment: I've marked your question as correct becuase my original question was about the syntax problem. I've deleted all tasks and activities using two queries instead of one.

Comment: @user792589 Sure. Tnanks... `:D`